# Basic security checks

Tags: australia, security-clearance

I may be going through a basic security clearance check soon.

Would this cover driving license suspension?

When I was abroad, I forgot to change my address and forgot to vote. Then I returned and updated my address I got a fine letter for the sum of $160. I paid the fine immediately. However I then got a follow up letter stating my license was now unsuspended. I didn’t even know it was suspended due to this.

Will this impact my Australian security clearance?

Thanks

Comment: No but living overseas for a long period might

Answer (score 3):

You can read the FAQs on the [AGSVA website](http://www.defence.gov.au/AGSVA/FAQ/clearance-subject.asp).

> Various reasons exist for why someone may be denied a security clearance. The most important factors in the security clearance process are your honesty, openness, and thoroughness in completing your security pack and responding to any questions.

They don't explicitly list red flags that will cause you to fail, but they are mostly looking for evidence that you will be susceptible to blackmail or bribery or that you have close ties to a foreign government.

They will not be interested in a fine for not voting, if you are worried just put an explanation for why on the form when you list it.